# How to lock Google Places Autocomplate to a Country

Tags: google-places-api

I am using the following code for my site which autocompletes the address and also displays the individual fields.

That works fine, however as the user types it is pulling up address from all over the world until they get further into the address.

I would like to Lock the country to the US for now and have tried several fiddles but cannot get the code to play nice.

Would appreciate some help on this - thanks

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123xyz&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>

<script>    
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
// [END region_geolocation]

</script>
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the following but whatever I try in there it makes no different.

```
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement}   */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});
```

Comment: why not just leave the location service on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following? You mentioned that you have tried several things, but didn't divulge more:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var options = {
        types: ['(geocode)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

If this doesn't work then set up a fiddle and show it to us, so we can try to get it working for you.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I did try your example however no luck I'm afraid. No streets coming up at all. Actually I did try that componentRestrictions also and didn't have any luck. 

However your code suggestion got me thinking and after a bit of fiddling I got it to work using the following ; 

`code`   
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {types: ['geocode'],  componentRestrictions: {country: 'US'}
    });
`code`

Tried to vote you up but not able to yet sorry.

Comment: That's fine Mark. You've basically done the same thing but coded it differently. I seem to remember a while back that if I defined the input and options variables first then things stopped working, as opposed to doing what you've done and including it all in one line of code. Now that my coding skills have improved I have less hiccups.